# how can we add external links on the proposal?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, substrate-node

I have created a custom chain using Substrate version `0.9.36`, and I've been using the governance module. When adding a proposal, there's a default column for external links set to "none." I would like to know how I can add my own external links. It would be very helpful if you could provide an example of how to include an external link.

[image]